# How do you create df column using str.contains to assign rows by category?

Tags: pandas, string, dataframe, categories

I want to add a column to a df and I want the values for the rows of that column to be a category based on strings contained in another attribute in the data.

For example, if another attribute contains a "P" or "S" I want the string within the new df column to say cat1. But if the other attribute contains an "O" I want the string in the df column to say cat2. Otherwise, I want the string to be cat3.

So essentially, I want to create a df column that considers what the string in another df column is and then assigns the row value based on what that string contains.

Comment: Does cat1 take priority over cat2 so that 'OP' is cat1 (or does it go based on which is found first?)

Comment: No, there is no priority. I want to iterate over the column and assign the cat for every i in the column based on that criteria.

Comment: Nevermind, this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36701689/assign-value-to-a-pandas-dataframe-column-based-on-string-condition) solved the issue